# Trouble with GLSL Shader

Tags: opengl, glsl, shader

I'm trying to make a basic Rim Lighting shader, but I think I'm doing something wrong.

It is supposed to look like this:
[image: Rim Light Correct]

But I'm getting this:
[image: Rim Light Wrong]

Here's my code:

Vertex:

```
            attribute vec3 AE_POSITION;
            attribute vec2 AE_TEXCOORD;
            attribute vec3 AE_NORMAL;
            attribute vec3 AE_TANGENT;

            uniform mat4 AE_MVP;
            uniform mat4 AE_Model;

            varying vec3 AE_WorldPosition;
            varying vec3 AE_WorldNormal;

            void main() {
                AE_WorldPosition = (AE_Model * vec4(AE_POSITION, 1.0)).xyz;
                AE_WorldNormal = normalize((AE_Model * vec4(AE_NORMAL, 1.0)).xyz);

                gl_Position = AE_MVP * AE_Model * vec4(AE_POSITION, 1.0);
            }
```

Fragment:

```
            varying vec3 AE_WorldPosition;
            varying vec3 AE_WorldNormal;

            uniform vec3 AE_EyePos;

            void main() {
                vec3 v = normalize(AE_EyePos - AE_WorldPosition);

                float rim = 1.0 - max(dot(v, AE_WorldNormal), 0.0);
                rim = smoothstep(0.6, 1.0, rim);
                vec3 finalRim = vec3(1.0, 0.0, 0.0) * vec3(rim);

                gl_FragColor = vec4(finalRim, 1.0);
            }
```

Comment: Can you explain the basic idea of rim lighting? It looks like if the parts at the rim are brightened up. Is this true? Because you are darkening the parts that are not on the rim. Btw, I would use `abs(dot(...))` instead of `max(dot(...), 0.0)` to calculate `rim`. And the constant red in your code is supposed to be the material color?

Comment: The rim light is the bright area btw.
The red is supposed to be the rim color.

Comment: Then, shouldn't you add `finalRim` to the result of another lighting model? Have you tried the `abs` function? It should give you only the rim. Currently, all normals that are facing towards the camera are clamped to `rim = 1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. **If I get it right you should add the red if `q=dot(camera_direction,surface_normal)` is near `0.0`**

   not sure why not white when your example has white rim instead you are modulating red color on the whole surface
2. **if this is 2nd render pass**

   then your image is already rendered so either throw away not rim fragments or add the source image texture and combine in fragment or use transparency and combine.
3. **if this is not multi pass render**

   then where are: `colors,textures,texcoords`,... for the surfaces? I would try something like this fragment:

   ```cpp
   float q,m=0.3f;
   vec4 col; // let this be surface computed color (does not matter for which of above approaches)
   vec3 v;

   // here compute the col if not multi pass

   v=normalize(AE_EyePos - AE_WorldPosition);
   q=dot(v, AE_WorldNormal);
   q*=q; // enhance rim gradient and also abs can use any even higher power...
   if (q<m) // rim size limit
    {
    q=1.0-(q/m);
    col.xyz+=vec3(1.0,0.0,0.0)*q; // use = for multi pass
    }
   // else discard; // if multi pass 
   gl_FragColor=col;
   ```